# Scikit Learn: Predict category based on a number of text-based features

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Predict which users find the review helpful (or "blank" if no one has found it useful so far). Either: 1) predict the string of users (assuming order is always alphabetical); or 2) for each user, predict whether or not they will find the review useful. For now there are a limited number of users (less than ten), and code for this is acceptable. But it is interesting to consider a future application which predicts many more users (let's say a few thousand or million possible users).

Sample data: train.csv

```
"id","title","review","user tags","user(s) who find review helpful"
"123","All movies!","I really love movies","love,all","Bill"
"456","No movies!","I really hate movies","hate,none","Jane"
"789","Great show!","That show was really great","great,really","Bill,Jane,Wanda"
"899","Interesting plot!","He makes the plot interesting","interesting,plot",""
"999","So tired!","The ending made me sleep","ending,tired,sleepy",""
```

Test: Use text from columns 1,2,3 to predict text-column 4. Ignore id numeric column 0.

So far I am using the guide here (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).

Current code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
'''text_clf = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',
            alpha=1e-3, random_state=42,
            max_iter=5, tol=None)),
])
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
])'''
text_clf = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf',
        MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5,
        hidden_layer_sizes=(50, 20),
        random_state=1, shuffle=True, max_iter=200)
    ),
])
data = pd.read_csv('./train.csv',
        error_bad_lines=False,header=None,sep=',',
        dtype={
            0: np.dtype('u8'), # id, 64-bit unsigned integer
            2: np.dtype('U'),  # title, unicode
            3: np.dtype('U'),  # review, unicode
            4: np.dtype('U'),  # tags, unicode
            5: np.dtype('U'),  # name(s), unicode
        })
# TODO: Split user names column by comma.
xtr = data.iloc[0:100000,1:5].astype(str).values
ytr = data.iloc[0:100000,5].values
xtest = data.iloc[100001:101000,1:5].values
ytest = data.iloc[100001:101000,5]
text_clf.fit(xtr, ytr)
predicted = text_clf.predict(xtest)
print(np.mean(predicted == ytest))
```

Which produces the following output:

```
---> 38 predicted = text_clf.predict(data.iloc[100001:101000,5].values)
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: I see that when you trained your pipeline, you used `data.iloc[0:100000,1:5].astype(str).values` for your `xtr`, so why not do the same with `xtest = data.iloc[100001:101000,1:5].astype(str).values`?

Comment: CountVectorizer() requires a single column with text data. You need to pass only that column to it.

Comment: How about: Concatenate rows 1,2,3,4 into one column, then use this column to predict column 5? (Actually this article does it a bit different: https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-on-multiple-columns-in-python-554043e05308)

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Jarad Ha ha ha - No!